# WCT WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO union validation

Tags: winapi

I am using WCT Api from C# code (using `pinvoke`) and I have this question :

When I call `GetThreadWaitChain` I get a result of WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO array:

WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681422(v=vs.85).aspx

WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO contains a union of two structs - which means that only one of the values are valid, how can I know what information to get from  the WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO struct?

Currently I am checking if ProcessId and ThreadId is 0 and by that I assume that the other union half is initialized...

This is my C# WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO struct model:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO
{
    public WCT_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType;
    public WCT_OBJECT_STATUS ObjectStatus;
    public _WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO_UNION Union;
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct _WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO_UNION
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public _WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO_LOCK_OBJECT LockObject;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public _WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO_THREAD_OBJECT ThreadObject;
}

public unsafe struct _WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO_LOCK_OBJECT
{
    /*The name of the object. Object names are only available for certain object, such as mutexes. If the object does not have a name, this member is an empty string.*/
    public fixed char ObjectName[WctApiConst.WCT_OBJNAME_LENGTH];
    /*This member is reserved for future use.*/
    public UInt64 Timeout;
    /*This member is reserved for future use.*/
    public UInt32 Alertable;
}

public struct _WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO_THREAD_OBJECT
{
    /*The process identifier.*/
    public UInt32 ProcessId;
    /*The thread identifier. For COM and ALPC, this member can be 0.*/
    public UInt32 ThreadId;
    /*The wait time.*/
    public UInt32 WaitTime;
    /*The number of context switches.*/
    public UInt32 ContextSwitches;
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I re-tagged this. The interop is not really important. It's a pure winapi question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is the if `ObjectType` is `WctThreadType` then you should read the `ThreadObject` part of the union. Otherwise you read the `LockObject` part of the union.

That this is the case can be gleaned from the various examples the MS provide. For instance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681418.aspx